# TinyMCE. after adding span cannot continue typing out of it

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to create a plugin for TinyMCE, so user can add floating tips for selected area.
All i need is to put selected content into span, i do it this way:

```
var formated = 
    '<span id="tooltip_widget_' + id + '">'
    + selectedtext
    + '</span>;
ed.selection.setContent(formated);
```

And it works well in Firefox, i can add text to span and continue typing out of it.
But in Chrome and IE all the following text goes into the added span. And the only way to continue typing out of it - via html editor.

I tried include additional caret placeholder span after the insertion and collapse after it and then delete this placeholder to make sure the caret will be after the inserted span.

But it doesn't help. In chrome and IE if caret is at the end of span, it continues typing inside this span.

Please advice how to solve this.

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) ? you can add your plugin code just above the tinymce init code

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is my plugin. http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/1

Comment: i am sorry, this does not work due to the fact that ExampleDialog is not a tinmce plugin. what i need is an example which shows exaxtly what you did till now

Comment: Now there is everything. Html below - dialog.htm http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/2

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/3

Comment: no, there are lots of js errors

Comment: Sorry. in not very much familiar with tinyMCE plugin and how to make it work in fiddle.tinymce. Now i fixed some errors but i don't know how to put there custom tinymce popup windows for my plugin. Now everything works, but my button still leads to nowhere. But it works on my site. i commented tinyMCEPopup.onInit.add(ExampleDialog.init, ExampleDialog); Please take a look. http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/7

Comment: I added a function plugin_work() trying to execute what you want to achieve using acustom button. But i am still not sure how your plugin works. Can you describe step by step what your plugin does. If you like you may modify the function plugin_worj to your needs. I think putting the most important code inside a custom button and fix the functionylity will work for the same code in your plugin even though we are not able to make popups work here.

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/12 Now it works. it generates what i need. Plugin puts selected text into span with unique id and adds additional hidden element corresponding to it with tooltip text. I added comments in the code. on every step. And this plugin works in FF. The problem is with IE and chrome, where user cannot continue typing out of the added span, and get all following text into it. I tried to add additional caret_placeholder span after with nbsp, and it helps. but adding spaces is not convenient way. I hope there is a way to solve this problem somehow. Dzcaab/12 - is working.

Comment: ok, what i need now is a step by step description of what works actually, and what not. Example: 1. User selects word "title" 2. user pushes button 3. user types 'word' result:user cannot type

Comment: got it. 1. User selects word "1asdasd"; 2. user pushes the button; 3. user see popUp with text field and type floating tip there(in fiddle he just presses the button); 4. plugin makes manipulations which i described in comments in code; 5. user now got floating tooltip under the selected text; 6. user continue typing and see that everything now goes into created span element with tip, and he cannot type out of it. All the following text will have this floating tooltip.

Comment: i am not able to see any tooltips?

Comment: No, it is visible only on front page. where jQuery and styles included. All i need from tineMCE is to generate html so user could make tooltips for the text in tinyMCE.

Comment: ok, thx for this description. it works till 5) but after i click the button i cannot write anything (probably because of loosing the focus). can you write further?

Comment: hm. that's right. Now i added ed.focus(). and you can type further. Now u can see as 1 described earlier. 6. user continue typing and see that everything now goes into created span element with tip, and he cannot type out of it. All the following text will have this floating tooltip.

Comment: ok, i can't find any differences to the chrome behavior

Comment: Difference is the following: <span id="tooltip_widget_1354786944613" class="tooltipedurl">test</span> Continue typing - In firefox. <span id="tooltip_widget_1354787031679" class="tooltipedurl">test Continue typing</span> - in chrome and IE. words "continue typing" got inside the created span, and there is no way to continue typing out of it except if i add extra space by my plugin(as i do right now in fiddle example). which is not good for end user. They don't want to see extra spaces if they just want to add floating tips to text. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: what about this: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/16

Comment: It will definitely help! But output html will look scary after 4-5 tips in the row. you think it is the only solution for now?

Comment: maybe something like this? http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/18

Comment: you can cleanup the content on formsubmit

Comment: That's right. Thank you for your help, it is solved i think.

Comment: ok, i will post the link to the latest fiddle as answer which you may accept then :). +1 to the question for providing a base fiddle

Comment: Sure, i am new here. have no idea how to accept you helpful answers. Please tell me, i don't see the button.

Comment: You just have to click on the check mark right under the votes (left of an answer). Plus you may upvote answers that you find helpfull (even those that you did not accept). It is kind of saying "thanks" for the support and/or quality of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found [in this fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dzcaab/18) or as code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function plugin_work(){

        var ed = tinymce.editors[0];
        var innerSpanId = 0;
        var node = ed.selection.getNode();

        // Get the selected contents as text and place it in the input
        if (ed.selection.getNode().className == "tooltipedurl") {

            var innerSpanId = node.id;
            if (innerSpanId != 0) {
                var innerSpanHTML = ed.dom.get('data_' + innerSpanId).innerHTML;
            }
        } else {

           var innerSpanHTML = ed.selection.getContent({format : 'html'});
        }

        var id = new Date().getTime();
        var node = ed.selection.getNode();


        if (node.className == "tooltipedurl") {
            var innerSpanId = node.id;
            if (innerSpanHTML != 0) {
                ed.dom.get('data_' + innerSpanId).innerHTML = innerSpanHTML;
            } else {
                ed.dom.remove(node);
                ed.selection.setContent(node.innerHTML);
                ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.get('data_' + innerSpanId));
                ed.focus();
            }
        } else {
            var formated =
                '<span id=\"tooltip_widget_' + id + '\" class=\"tooltipedurl\" name="tip">'
                + innerSpanHTML
                + '</span><span id="caret_placeholder_' + id + '" name="caret_placeholder">\u200b</span>';

            ed.selection.setContent(formated);

            var rng = tinymce.DOM.createRng();  // the range obj
            var $caret_placeholder = $(ed.getBody()).find ('#caret_placeholder_'+id);    // find the correct selector so that caret_placeholder is the element of your editor text
//            rng.setStart(caret_placeholder.firstChild, f.textFragment.value.length); // 0 is the offset : here it will be at the beginning of the line.
//            rng.setEnd(caret_placeholder.firstChild, f.textFragment.value.length);

//console.log(caret_placeholder);

            rng.setStartAfter($caret_placeholder.get(0));
            rng.setEndAfter($caret_placeholder.get(0));
            ed.selection.setRng(rng);

            //ed.selection.select(caret_placeholder);
            //$(caret_placeholder).html('');

            ed.focus();

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), 'span', {id : 'data_tooltip_widget_' + id, style : 'display:none'}, innerSpanHTML);
            ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
                if ($caret_placeholder = $(ed.getBody()).find ('#caret_placeholder_'+id)) {
                    var content = $caret_placeholder.get(0).innerHTML;
                    ed.dom.remove($caret_placeholder.get(0));
                    ed.selection.setContent(content);
                }
            });
        }
}

tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.floatingtipsPlugin', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            // Register the command so that it can be invoked by using tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mcefloatingtips');
            ed.addCommand('mcefloatingtips', function() {
                var se = ed.selection;
                // No selection and not in span
                if (se.isCollapsed() && se.getNode().className != "tooltipedurl") {
                    return;
                }

                ed.windowManager.open({
                    file : url + '/dialog.htm',
                    width : 320 + parseInt(ed.getLang('floatingtips.delta_width', 0)),
                    height : 120 + parseInt(ed.getLang('floatingtips.delta_height', 0)),
                    inline : 1
                }, {
                    plugin_url : url, // Plugin absolute URL
                    some_custom_arg : 'custom arg' // Custom argument
                });
            });

            // Register floatingtips button
            ed.addButton('floatingtips', {
                title : 'Add/Edit floating tip',
                cmd : 'mcefloatingtips',
                image : url + '/img/floating_tips.gif'
            });

            // Add a node change handler
            ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, n) {
                var se = ed.selection;
                cm.setActive('floatingtips', se.getNode().className == "tooltipedurl");
                cm.setDisabled('floatingtips', se.isCollapsed() && se.getNode().className != "tooltipedurl");
            });

            ed.contentCSS.push(url + '/css/floatingtips.css');
        },

        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },

        getInfo : function() {
            return {
                longname : 'floatingtips plugin',
                author : 'Some author',
                authorurl : 'http://tinymce.moxiecode.com',
                infourl : 'http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/floatingtips',
                version : "1.0"
            };
        }
    });

tinymce.PluginManager.add('floatingtips', tinymce.plugins.floatingtipsPlugin);

/**
 * 
 * Here goes dialog.js
 * What exactly my plugin does
 * 
 *  ================== GOAL =====================
 * Goal - to wrap selected text with span like this: 
 * <span class="tooltipedurl", id="tooltip_widget_" + {someuniueID}> SELECTED TEXT </span>
 * Add to the end of the editor hidden element with tooltip text like this: 
 * <span id="data_tooltip_widget_ + {someuniueID} style="display:none"> TOOLTIP TEXT </span>
 * 
  */

 /**
  * ================= ALGORITHM ==================
  * If some text selected, or if we have caret inside span with class tooltipedurl.
  * We got plugin buton - active.
  * On click we see popup form with two fields.
  * first with selected text, (it is hidden, user shouldn't be able to modify it from popup form)
  * second is the tip input(textarea filed) we load here old tip if the caret inside the span with tip.
  * 
  * if text selected:
  * we got it from the popup form {f.textFragment.value} and replace it with 
  * <span id=\"tooltip_widget_' + id + '\" class=\"tooltipedurl\" name="tip">'+ f.textFragment.value + '</span>
  * also we create hidden span in the end of editor with tip value from the form {f.newTip.value}
  * tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), 'span', {id : 'data_tooltip_widget_' + id, style : 'display:none'}, f.newTip.value);
  * 
  * if caret inside the span which already has tooltip
  * we have in popup form current tooltip message and can edit it and put new value to the corresponding hidden span
  * ed.dom.get('data_' + innerSpanId).innerHTML = f.newTip.value;
  * 
  * if the new tip value = 0, we delete span which contains the text and delete correspondig 
  * hiden element with tooltip text
  * 
  * more detailed comments i added to the script below
  */

var ExampleDialog = {
    init : function() {
        var ed = tinyMCEPopup.editor;

        // f is a form from PopUp 
        var f = document.forms[0];

        // if selection inside the span with class tooltipedurl we will put here the id of this span
        var innerSpanId = 0;

        var node = ed.selection.getNode();

        // Get the selected contents as text and place it in the input fields if we are inside the span with class tooltipedurl
        if (ed.selection.getNode().className == "tooltipedurl") {

            var innerSpanId = node.id;
            //taking all the text to the input from the span even if only part of it was selected
            f.textFragment.value = node.innerText;
            if (innerSpanId != 0) {
                //taking current tooltip text from the corresponding hidden span
                f.newTip.value = ed.dom.get('data_' + innerSpanId).innerHTML;
            }
        } else {
            //if selected text is not in the span with class tooltipedurl we just get as html to apply tooltip later
            f.textFragment.value = ed.selection.getContent({format : 'html'});

        }
    },

    insert : function() {
        var ed = tinyMCEPopup.editor;
        var f = document.forms[0];
        var id = new Date().getTime();
        var node = ed.selection.getNode();

        //if selection is inside the span#tooltipedurl - we gonna edit tooltip text
        if (node.className == "tooltipedurl") {
            var innerSpanId = node.id;
            if (f.newTip.value != 0) {
                //If new tooltip is not 0, we replace inner html of correspondig span in the end of editor
                ed.dom.get('data_' + innerSpanId).innerHTML = f.newTip.value;
            } else {
                //If new tooltip value is 0 - we delete correspondig span in the end of editor and remove <span> tags from text
                ed.dom.remove(node);
                ed.selection.setContent(node.innerHTML);
                ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.get('data_' + innerSpanId));
            }
        } else {
            //if selection doesn't have tooltip, we place it in the tags with unique id and class tooltipedurl
            var formated =
                '<span id=\"tooltip_widget_' + id + '\" class=\"tooltipedurl\" name="tip">'
                + f.textFragment.value
                + '</span>';
            ed.selection.setContent(formated);

            /**
             * THE PROBLEM IS
             * when we add this span and user trying to continue typing.
             * in Chrome and IE all the following text goes in this new span.
             * In firefox it works OK.
             * 
             */

            //Here i am trying to put caret right after added span with dom.range
            var rng = tinymce.DOM.createRng();  // the range obj
            var caret_placeholder = ed.dom.get('tooltip_widget_' + id);   
//            rng.setStart(caret_placeholder.firstChild, f.textFragment.value.length); 
//            rng.setEnd(caret_placeholder.firstChild, f.textFragment.value.length);

            rng.setStartAfter(caret_placeholder);
            rng.setEndAfter(caret_placeholder);
            ed.selection.setRng(rng);
            //But it doesn't help...

            //creating invisible element with tooltip message in the end of the editor
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), 'span', {id : 'data_tooltip_widget_' + id, style : 'display:none'}, f.newTip.value);

        }

        tinyMCEPopup.close();

    }
};


/**
 * I don't know how to include popup window from my plugin here
 * But ih has 2 fields 
 * f.textFragment.value ==> it is the selected text  (this field is hidden)
 * f.newTip.value ==> text input with the tip.
 * 
 * so when user selects some text and clicks add floating tip button. he sees the form with 1 text field and can add new tooltip or edit old one
 * 
 */


//tinyMCEPopup.onInit.add(ExampleDialog.init, ExampleDialog);


// Initialize TinyMCE with the new plugin and listbox
tinyMCE.init({
    plugins : '-example, floatingtips', // - tells TinyMCE to skip the loading of the plugin
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "code,mylistbox,mysplitbutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink, floatingtips",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"
});


</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
        <textarea name="content">
        test
        </textarea>
</form>
<div onclick="plugin_work();" style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;width:70px;">Button</div>
```